# Change the privacy of a post by a friend on my Timeline

Tags: facebook, privacy

Is there a way to change the privacy of a single post by my friend on my timeline?

Also hiding from timeline is not an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to change the privacy of a single post by my friend on my timeline?

No, you can only change the privacy of your post. Friends' post privacy settings can be changed by them.

Comment: i called up my friend & he said he is unable to change its privacy either...anyway will now just hide it from timeline

Comment: @AyushShanker Did it answer your question?

Comment: no..otherwise i would have marked it as answered for sure...also the answer doesn't quite seems to be correct...my friend said that the privacy was locked to "Ayush(thats me) controls who sees posts on his timeline"

Comment: @Ayush probably you both are tagged. Remove tags & then change privacy settings. Either way, you haven't told us the full story & I've pretty much verified that if _your friend_ hd posted it then only he has the power to change the privacy settings of _his_ post